# How to get facebook video thumbnail from a given video ID using php

Tags: php, facebook, thumbnails

I want to get thumbnail of facebook videos from a given video ID .

I use the preg_match function to get facebook video ID from a given url retrieved from database

```
preg_match("~/videos/(?:t\.\d+/)?(\d+)~i", $value->url, $matches);
$video_id = $matches[1];
echo ' <div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/'.$video_id.'/"></div>';
```

I want to posted on website with something like this:

```
<img src="VIDEO_IMAGE.<?php echo $video_id ?>.jpg">
```

I don't know if it' posssible? !

Comment: I just get it: Find my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777456/8786244

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image source is wrong try using

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID/picture" />
```

Example : https://graph.facebook.com/10153231379946729/picture

Comment: Thank you so much! you saved my life :D

and how about getting a large or medium image size ?
is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: @AnasAmine there is only two type of thumb in fb, small and big. Small can be grabbed easily with the link below; but big has some issue. Please check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773155/how-to-get-big-facebook-video-thumbnail/32168767?noredirect=1#comment52234918_32168767