# Facebook Graph API get video info from user upload

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Though it is possible to get video information uploaded by a page, how do you get video info uploaded by a user which is publicly available?

This can be done when it is uploaded by a Page.

`https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID/picture
https://graph.facebook.com/VIDEO_ID`

But not when uploaded by a user.

I know this is possible because there are free online facebook downloaders that could grab the video of a user. Of course it should be publicly available.

Source: [How to get Facebook video thumbnail from its video id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000856/how-to-get-facebook-video-thumbnail-from-its-video-id/7068081#7068081)

Comment: You use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/

Comment: You need the user to grant your app permission to read their videos first. (Public or not does not matter when it comes to the API.)

Comment: But why does online video downloaders out there does not need app permission? It's not even an app. Just a website that could scrape user videos.